# How do I filter out data after a groupby?

Tags: pandas, group-by

Hey question guys I'm just trying to do some filtering on columns by Gender.
Basically I just want it to drop all BMI values that are below .005% based on gender.
I'd love to learn how to do this using a function and groupby but if there's an easy method i'm also okay with that.

```
def Bmi_Quartile(X):
    z = (X['BMI'].quantile(.005))
    print(z)
    print(X['BMI'])
    if(X['BMI'] <= z):
        print(X['BMI'])


BmiDF.groupby('gender').apply(Bmi_Quartile)
```

Comment: Can post sample input data and expected output?

Comment: Can you try this & see? `BmiDF.loc[BmiDF['BMI'] < BmiDF.groupby('gender').BMI.transform(lambda x: x.quantile(.005))]`